# Why does bittrex return invalid_market error?

Tags: php

In php, I submit the value just as it appears in the developer documentation on bittrex.com: 
https://bittrex.com/home/api

```
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/buylimit?market=BTC-LTC&quantity=1.2&rate=1.3?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
```

The call succeeds but it returns the invalid_market error. There is a similar question on GitHub but the solution doesn't appear to apply in this case. 
github.com/timmolter/XChange/issues/1414

Is my charset (utf-8) the issue? Can't figure it out...

Comment: Could it be that you have used `?apikey=API_KEY` and `?apikey='.$apikey.`

Comment: Unfortunately, that was just my copy/paste error on Stack Overflow- I've modified it in the original post. I'm submitting the api_key value correctly, otherwise it would throw an error on that.

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently repeated the apikey parameter at the beginning and end of the uri. Try this :

```
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/buylimit?market=BTC-LTC&quantity=1.2&rate=1.3&apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste error on stack Overflow only unfortunately. The API key value is working and the call of succeeding otherwise it would throw in API key error instead or in addition to the invalid Market error.

Comment: maybe send their support an e-mail with your problem then. I see nothing else wrong in your call acording to the documentation. But sometimes, the documentation is not updated as it should when an API is upgraded, better let them know your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this error - my php syntax was incorrect when pulling the variables into to $uri string. I updated as follows:

$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/buylimit?market='.$market.'&quantity='.$quanity.'&rate='.$rate&apikey.'&apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;

Thanks for the help, here!